# Error 126 - Incorrect key file for table - 4,8 GB table size

Tags: mysql

I want to remove duplicates from a table that contains 280.717.107 entries.
The table consist in 3 fields (no primary key) `user_id`, `from_user_id`, `value`.
At some point there are some repetitive entries that I want to remove.

Let's say something like this:

> ```
> user_id  from_user_id  value
> 1        2             4
> 2        2             4
> 3        2             4
> 1        2             4 #duplicate
> 5        2             4
> 8        2             4
> 9        2             4
> 9        2             4 #duplicate
> ```

My table is having 4,8 GB size (I dumped it)
So I went to the server (not phpMyAdmin) and in MySQL I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM my_table;
```

At one point I get this error message :

> "Error 126 - Incorrect key file for table"

Some people say that this message might be because the memory is full.

My question is can I bypass this memory crash somehow and create this new table with my distinct entries?

Comment: You could try doing it in batches by applying a filter like `where user_id < 1000` and increasing the value each time.

Comment: This should be due to full disk, not memory as far as I know. Are you sure you have sufficient room for such operation? Also, what @Stijn said is valid, do the operation in batches rather than in 1 go.

Comment: @Stijn, your option is valid with limit and offset. Please add it as a response so I can accept your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing it in batches by applying a filter like

```
where user_id <= 1000
```

and increasing the value each time. So the next would be

```
where user_id > 1000 and user_id <= 2000
```

Like you mentioned in your comment, `limit` and `offset` would also work.